# Windows Phone ListView object with list

Tags: list, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a object which contains 5 list of object, and I would like to display this object in only one listview, I tried a lot of different things, like groups, but I can't find a solution. This is my object :

```
    public class SearchResult
{
    public List<User> artist { get; set; }
    public List<User> user { get; set; }
    public List<Music> music { get; set; }
    public List<Album> album { get; set; }
    public List<Pack> pack { get; set; }
}
```

How can I bind 5 list and display the information a need for each one by using a Template.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you draw the picture? How do you what it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for something like the Search results in the XBox Music app?
It is probably just multiple ListViews, but if you really want all of them in a single ListView, you have to:

- Put your lists together in a ListOfLists (List>), so you can use it with CollectionViewSource.
- Or: Implement IGrouping on your SearchResult.

Then you can just use the **GroupStyle** on the Listview and **ItemTemplateSelector** will help you use different Templates on each Type.

So you will have to change your data structure if you want to bind it.